# I have Product and Category Many to Many Relation. I need to fetch Product where category_id(in pivot table) = [1,2,3,4]

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-8

I have Product and Category Many to Many Relation. I need to fetch Product where category_id(in pivot table) = [1,2,3,4]

in my Category Model

```
public function all_product($categories_ids): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->wherePivotIn('category_id', $categories_ids);
}
```

and in controller

```
    $categories_ids = [1,2,3,4];
    $category = Category::where('slug_id', $request->input('slug_id'))->first();
    $product =  $category->all_product($categories_ids)->get();
    return $product;
```

here I get only associated product with that  $category. but I need all product whose category_id are $categories_ids = [1,2,3,4].

please help me to solve this query. thank you